# Not getting .cab file link in windows phone 8.1 crash report

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, crash-reports

Has anyone had any issues getting the .cab files when trying to look at your applications crash reports? I'm getting stach traces in the report all of the sudden that look like this:

```
windows_ni  STOWED_EXCEPTION_windows_ni+4bf1fd
```

and

> STOWED_EXCEPTION_System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException_csr_shoppingnanny_client_ni!CSR.ShoppingNanny.Client.Common.SuspensionManager.SaveFrameNavigationState+22cc0

I have a .cab column in the xlsx file, but there is nothing in it.

Any ideas?